# Maven - Could not transfer artifact caused by Blocked mirror for repositories

Tags: docker, maven

I got this error when deploying Maven through GitlabCI, docker image: **maven:3-jdk-8**.

```
Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mycompany.app:app-all:0.9.3-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not transfer artifact com.mycompany:parent:pom:8 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): 
Blocked mirror for repositories: [app-releases (http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/repositories/app-releases, default, releases+snapshots), 
app-snapshots (http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/repositories/app-snapshots, default, releases+snapshots)] and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
```

I found some answers here about editing the mirrors in the settings.xml file. I add the mirrors with blocked: false in /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>app-releases</id>
      <mirrorOf>app-releases</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/repositories/app-releases</url>
      <blocked>false</blocked>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>app-snapshots</id>
      <mirrorOf>app-snapshots</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com/content/repositories/app-snapshots</url>
      <blocked>false</blocked>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

But still got this error, I don't get why it search artifact in maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) while option -X (debug) shows the settings.xml file is being used so the mirrors I set should be used.

```
1100 [DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
1100 [DEBUG] Reading user settings from /root/.m2/settings.xml
```

Did I make a mistake in the mirrors definition ?

Comment: See for details with http blocking: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html

Comment: As said it this release note : "Options to fix are: keep the dependency version but define a mirror in your settings." It's what I am trying to do here

Comment: Simplest is to define a `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` because you are using a repository manager...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is probably due to Maven 3.8.1 blocking http repositories.

I would switch to https repositories if your company supports them.

Comment: As mentioned in the https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html : 
There are 2 Options to fix :
-upgrade the dependency version to a newer version that replaced the obsolete HTTP repository URL with a HTTPS one,
-keep the dependency version but define a mirror in your settings.
I am searching to fix this without changing to https

Answer (score 5):

You can do a mirroring in local. Add this in `~/.m2/settings.xml`(which is a user-specific version of `<maven_dir>/conf/settings.xml`.

```xml
<settings>
    <!-- if you need http connection, enable it and don't block -->
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
          <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
          <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
          <url>http://0.0.0.0</url>
          <blocked>false</blocked>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    ...
</settings>
```

I even changed the url to `file:/home/<my_user>/.m2/repository`, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issues.

```
Maven Version 3.8.6
JDK Java17
```

The problem is maven was referring to some dependencies which are listed over `http` protocol, however with latest maven it comes with the mirror to block the http dependencies as it want to encourage or enforce dependencies only over `https`

Solution

1. Switch to the https dependencies.
2. If https version of dependencies are not available then we can locally suppress the error by commenting the `http-block` mirror

Below steps are for macos, so do relevant for your OS

Run `mvn --version` to find the location of maven installation
bash-3.2$ `mvn --version`
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec`

Now go to conf and open settings.xml
Comment the below mirror

```
 <mirror>
      <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
      <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
      <blocked>true</blocked>
    </mirror>
```

Save it and re run the maven job, it should fix your issue.